# commitTime isn't ... actual commit time

Tags: jgit

I'm using JGit to run some commits, but I notice the commit time in log is the same for all my commits, even the process is few seconds long. After some testing, I can confirm commits are created with commitTime = time the Repository has been opened.

Sounds like a bug, don't you think ?

Answer (score 1):

I just understood commit time is set via committer PersonIdent object.